# bus error on sem_wait()

Tags: c, linux, semaphore

I am writing a multi-process program using named semaphores, in the master process I am opening the semaphore with the following code

```
semaphore = sem_open("/msema",O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC,00777,1);      
if (semaphore == SEM_FAILED)
    perror("SEMAPHORE");
```

and in the child program

```
count_sem=sem_open("/msema",O_RDWR);
if(count_sem==SEM_FAILED) 
 {
 perror("sem_open");
 return 1;
 }
```

on sem_wait()

```
   do {
   errno=0;  
printf("BeforeSemWait\n");  
    rtn=sem_wait(count_sem);
printf("afterSemWait\n");
  } while(errno==EINTR);
  if(rtn < 0) {
  printf("Error\n");
  perror("sem_wait()");
  sem_close(count_sem);
  return 1;
 }
```

I am getting a bus error from sem_wait()

```
 BeforeSemWait

 Program received signal SIGBUS, Bus error.
 0x00a206c9 in sem_wait@@GLIBC_2.1 () from /lib/libpthread.so.0`
```

What am I doing wrong?

edit: entire code: 
master.c: http://pastebin.com/3MnMjUUM
worker.c  http://pastebin.com/rW5qYFqg

Comment: How are `semaphore` and `count_sem` declared/defined? They should be `sem_t *semaphore;`, etc... Also, `sem_wait()` can return -1 for reasons other than `EINTR`, you might want to check those...

Comment: Is that the only call you do to `sem_wait()`? Could you `printf()` something in the `do{  }while();` loop in order to know if the signal is sent on the first iteration or not?

Comment: It is in the first iteration, I originally did have a print statement there, and yes, it is the only call to sem_wait()

Answer (score 0):

You must have somewhere else a bug in your program. The following works here (O_TRUNC is not needed):
semproducer.c:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
int main () {
  sem_t *sem=sem_open("/msema",O_RDWR|O_CREAT /* |O_TRUNC*/ ,00777,1);
  if (sem==SEM_FAILED) {
    perror("sem_open");
  }
  else {
    while (1) {
      sem_post (sem);
      printf ("sem_post done\n");
      sleep (5);
    }
  }
}
```

semconsumer.c:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <errno.h>
int main () {
  sem_t *count_sem=sem_open("/msema",O_RDWR);
  if(count_sem==SEM_FAILED) {
    perror("sem_open");
    return 1;
  }
  do {
    int rtn;
    do {
      errno=0;
      rtn=sem_wait(count_sem);
    } while(errno==EINTR);
    if(rtn < 0) {
      perror("sem_wait()");
      sem_close(count_sem);
      return 1;
    }
    printf ("sema signalled\n");
  } while (1);
}
```

compile with `gcc semproducer.c -o semproducer -lrt` and  `gcc semconsumer.c -o semconsumer -lrt`

Comment: The error is not somewhere else, I edited the question above to reflect how I determined this

Comment: Also, I tried your code, and got
     `Program received signal SIGBUS, Bus error.`
     `0x00a20915 in sem_post@@GLIBC_2.1 () from /lib/libpthread.so.0`

Comment: So then there must be something wrong with some libraries. I have here installed `gcc version 4.5.0 20100604 [gcc-4_5-branch revision 160292] (SUSE Linux)`,  `/libpthread-2.11.2.so`, `/lib/librt-2.11.2.so`, `uname -a` says `Linux hurx 2.6.34.10-0.6-desktop #1 SMP PREEMPT 2011-12-13 18:27:38 +0100 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this exact error.

It was because I hadn't linked in the Real-Time library that provides POSIX real-time functionality. The commenter above briefly mentioned the "-lrt" parameter in his solution, but did not emphasize it as the reason that you were getting your exception. You can verify this with the following code:

```
int main(void)
{
   
    sem_t* my_sem = sem_open("/test_sem", O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR, 0);
    sem_wait(my_sem);
}
```

Assuming this is  in the file "test.c" and I run the following:

```
gcc ./test.c -o test.out
./test.out
```

I get the Bus Error Output:

```
Bus error
```

But with the following command:

```
gcc ./test.c -o test.out -lrt
./test.out
```

The program does not except, and instead waits on the semaphore forever which is expected with a value of zero.

You should NOT pass -lrt, however. The linux documentation for [sem_wait(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_wait.3.html) indicates that the correct command is "-pthread". Substituting "-lrt" with "-pthread" in my testing indicates that it has the same effect, so the list of flags passed by -pthread on Linux likely includes "-lrt".

As such, the correct compiler invocation would be

```
gcc ./test.c -o test.out -pthread
```